# In a master-master setup, what command or files do I edit so that it can auto-increment by 2?

Tags: mysql, database, replication, auto-increment

One server increment 1, 3, 5.

The other server increment 2, 4, 6

Comment: If the idea is to avoid duplicates, why not use GUIDs instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this insightful tutorial: http://www.howtoforge.com/mysql_master_master_replication#comment-12927

Make Master 1 only auto-increment odd numbers by adding this to my.cnf under [mysqld]:

```
auto_increment_increment= 2
auto_increment_offset   = 1
```

Make Master 2 only auto-increment even numbers by adding this to my.cnf under [mysqld]:

```
auto_increment_increment= 2
auto_increment_offset   = 2
```